# Using two vectors, one with variables like x, y, z, one with values like 1, 2, 3, to make an equation like x=1, y=2, z=3?

Tags: c++, variables, vector, iterator

I am using a program that is based on C++, but has its own syntax.  For example, this is how I would set the variable x equal to 2:

```
x() = 2;
```

I read in variables and their initial values from an external file.  The data are stored in two vectors.  Vector 1 holds my labels, "x(), y(), and z()."  Vector2 holds values, like "1, 2, 3."

My problem is that I need to put the data together so that the program executes the expressions that tie particular values to particular variables. For example, x() = 2, etc.

How can I do this?  If I say: Vector1[0] = 2, then I simply overwrite the element of Vector1 with 2.  I don't get: x() = 2.

Comment: So you want to evaluate a mathematical expression which has assignments and variables in it?

Comment: I think we need to know the identity of this "program that is based on C++ but has its own syntax".  The answer depends on what is possible in this context.

Comment: If this "program that is based on C++ but has its own syntax" only has variables, and does not have arrays, or some data structure that allows for an arbitrary number of values, then you are out of luck I think.  The way you describe your problem, your input files contain vectors that may have an arbitrary number of variable names and values.  This requires that the language be capable of managing an arbitrary number of variables, i.e., an array.

Comment: @CharlesBretana The OP says they have vectors.  The question in my mind is whether they have `map<string, int *>`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It is a research code.  It has all the capabilities of C++.  So yes, it should have maps.  I have to apologize, because this is probably a silly question.  But I just can't figure out how to ensure that expressions like, x() = 2 and y() = 2 are executed from the read-in data.  The two vectors always have the same dimensions.

Comment: @Ant What do you mean saying `are executed from the read-in data`?

Comment: Tsar Ioann, sorry for not being clear...  I mean that I need to type: x() = 2.0 (for example) for a variable to have a value. I do not know how to combine the contents of the two vectors so that I do this.  I am aware that this is probably a trivial question, but it has been a while since I dealt with C++.  Thanks for everyone's patience!!

Comment: @Ant You do not need to combine anything when you use `map`. Using two vectors to solve this task will make you a lot of unnecessary problems. You just should do the thing I wrote in the answer below. If you still want to use two vectors, than iterate through the first one and find if there is `x`. If not - add a new element. If there is - replace value with same index in second vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it's better to use `std::map` for solving this problem.

For example:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;

//x() = 2
m["x"] = 2;

//y() = 3
m["y"] = 3;

std::cout << m["x"] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Deleted this comment because I realized my problem.  Apologies!